# add some text to a bunch of lines

Tags: sed

The first command does work as expected but not the second one.
I want to add some text either at the beginning or the end.

```
# grep `date +'%y%m%d'` /var/log/mysqld.log
100101 10:56:00  mysqld started
100101 10:56:02  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 1 2052750649

# sed 's/^/computer /g' < grep `date +'%y%m%d'` /var/log/mysqld.log
bash: grep: No such file or directory

# expected output
computer 100101 10:56:00  mysqld started
computer 100101 10:56:02  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 1 2052750649
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you wrote it with input redirection, it looks for a file called `grep` in the current directory and tries to *read* its contents, not *execute* it. You need to use a pipe instead:

```
grep `date +'%y%m%d'` /var/log/mysqld.log | sed 's/^/computer /'
```

I also removed the 'g' modifier from your sed as it is completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Just one awk command

```
awk -vd=$(date +'%y%m%d') '$0~d{ print "computer "$0 }' /var/log/mysqld.log
```