# error out to logger

Tags: unix

I use logger command to log messages to /var/log/messages But How do I use logger to save the standard out, error out messages? Something like this does not work.

```
grep `date +'%y%m%d'` /var/log/mysqld.log | sed 's/^/computer /' | logger 2> logger
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing redirection to a process (pipes, or `|`) with redirection to a file (`>`).

You need to redirect *stderr* to *stdout* by using `2>&1`, and then pipe (`|`) to your logger process.

e.g.

```
grep ....  2>&1 | logger
```

This assumes you're using `sh` or a variant. The syntax is different for `csh`. It's worth having a look at [this excerpt](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix/upt/ch13_01.htm) from [Unix Power Tools](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596003302) for more info (especially as [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988825/add-some-text-to-a-bunch-of-lines) seems strongly related).

Comment: I have just ordered "Unix Power Tools" book. Thanks for that link.
I have not tested your command. But it must be working.